# How to debug docker container on user defined network that can not access internet

Tags: networking, docker

Networking is not one of my strengths so forgive me if I am missing something here.

I am using Centos7 as my host OS. Docker version 17.03.0-ce, build 60ccb22.

I create a network using:

`docker network create --driver=bridge --subnet=10.19.0.0/16 development`

I run a container using:

`sudo docker run -dit --name=php-nginx1 --net=development --ip=10.19.74.23  --volume /vagrant/wordpress:/var/www/wordpress --expose 80 php-nginx`

When I ping 216.58.216.36 ( google ) from inside the container results are:

`PING 216.58.216.36 (216.58.216.36) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 10.19.74.23 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable`

If I run the container without specifying the network I can ping 216.58.216.36 with no problem.

The results of ifconfig on the host are

```
docker0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet 172.17.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 0.0.0.0
    inet6 fe80::42:7fff:fee2:8f4e  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
    ether 02:42:7f:e2:8f:4e  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 13674  bytes 609692 (595.4 KiB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 16644  bytes 182882110 (174.4 MiB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet 10.0.2.15  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 10.0.2.255
    inet6 fe80::5054:ff:fe22:5b53  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
    ether 52:54:00:22:5b:53  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 322262  bytes 409758704 (390.7 MiB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 47924  bytes 3329709 (3.1 MiB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

eth1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet 10.19.74.21  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 10.19.74.255
    inet6 fe80::a00:27ff:feb9:e12  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
    ether 08:00:27:b9:0e:12  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 2  bytes 120 (120.0 B)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 28  bytes 2016 (1.9 KiB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
    inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
    inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
    loop  txqueuelen 1  (Local Loopback)
    RX packets 84  bytes 7244 (7.0 KiB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 84  bytes 7244 (7.0 KiB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Ifconfig form the container is:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 02:42:0a:13:4a:17  
      inet addr:10.19.74.23  Bcast:0.0.0.0  Mask:255.255.0.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::42:aff:fe13:4a17/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:16 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:8 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
      RX bytes:1296 (1.2 KB)  TX bytes:648 (648.0 B)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
      inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
      inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
      RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
      RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

Route form the countainer results in:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         10.19.0.1       0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
10.19.0.0       *               255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 eth0
```

Route from the host results in:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         gateway         0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 eth0
10.0.2.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 eth0
10.19.0.0       0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 br-    ca991944118f
10.19.74.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth1
link-local      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1003   0        0 eth1
172.17.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 docker0
```

I don't know what to do about the downvote. I have looked at other questions relating to docker containers not being able to access the internet but they all seem to relate to containers not being able to access external addresses at all. This container can access the internet if it is not assigned to the network I created, but not when connected to the network I created.

Since my networking knowledge is limited I am struggling to find where to start in debugging this issue. A solution to this particular problem would be great, but a way to debug this issue would be even better.

How can I debug this issue?

Comment: I can think of nearly zero reasons why you have to go through the manual networking config for a wordpress container.

Comment: What re the downsides to using the manual networking config now that it's working for me? What would your recommendation be to architect this if not using manual networking?

Comment: Portability....

Comment: You're right. I'm no longer using manual networking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You appear to be trying to configure a docker network and container with the same IP subnet as you have on eth1. This will result in traffic that can't be properly routed since linux doesn't know which of the two it should send traffic to. Best case (which you appear to have experienced) it keeps sending traffic to eth1 and your container cannot communicate. Worst case, you can't talk to anything via eth1.

The solution is to not try to treat containers as a lightweight VM, because they are not. Spin them up inside docker with an unused subnet (docker will try to do this automatically with networks you create if you don't force it otherwise). Allow the containers to get any random IP inside that network. And for outside connections that need to access docker containers, publish a port on the docker host and have outsiders connect to that port on the host to talk to your container.

Docker's [networking user guide](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/) has more details on how networking works inside of docker and commands to use.

Comment: Thank you. That was the problem.